# which web.config to use in AspNetBoilerplate startup template?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Downloaded a free startup template and got a zip archive with the whole solution.

When unzipping the archive on windows I got a message asking whether to overwrite existing web.config file.
And indeed there are two web.config files below /src/myapp.Web.Host/.
The two file names differ in upper/lower case of the first letter.

One is named `Web.config` and the other `web.config` and the content differs.
Which one shall I use?

Options used:

- ASP.NET Core 2.x
- Target Framework: .NET Core (Cross Platform)
- SPA with Angular
- Include login, ...
- One Solution

Comment: that does sound a bit strange.  i would get a fresh template and download into a fresh/empty directory.

Comment: bug it is then -)

Comment: I also tried same. getting two web.config files. It may be a bug. web.config (small w) was used to be for service side solution and Web.config (capital W was for Angular solution). If you don't want to wait you can download the template without one solution till it's fixed by aspnetboilerplate developers

Comment: You can track the issue status https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the issue fixes, you can use this web.config content...I tried, works perfectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- ASPNET CORE SETTINS -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>

    <aspNetCore
      processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
      arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
      stdoutLogEnabled="false"
      stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
      forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"
      startupTimeLimit="3600"
      requestTimeout="23:00:00" />

    <!-- REMOVE INFO LEAK HEADERS -->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

    <!-- MIME TYPES -->
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff"  mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>

    <!-- IIS URL Rewrite for Angular routes -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/files/2149283/Web.config.zip